# How can I make separate Modals with different descriptions?

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, popup

I'm making a car dealership website, when a user clicks on a button below a car image, I want the modal to display information about that car only. At the moment I have managed to make several modal buttons but all show the same information.

How can I create separate modals with separate information?

```js
import "./Modal.css";
import Pagani from '../Images/pagani2.jpg';
import Pagani1 from '../Images/pagani.jpg';
import p1 from '../Images/p1.jpg';
import r342 from '../Images/r342.jpg';


import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Modal from '@mui/material/Modal';

const style = {
  position: 'absolute',
  top: '50%',
  left: '50%',
  transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
  width: 400,
  bgcolor: 'background.paper',
  border: '2px solid #000',
  boxShadow: 24,
  p: 4,
};

export default function BasicModal() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const handleOpen = () => setOpen(true);
  const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);

return (
<div>
  <Button onClick={handleOpen}>Open modal</Button>
  <Modal
    open={open}
    onClose={handleClose}
    aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
    aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
  >
    <Box sx={style}>
      <Typography id="modal-modal-title" variant="h6" component="h2">
        Text in a modal
      </Typography>
      <Typography id="modal-modal-description" sx={{ mt: 2 }}>
        Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula.
      </Typography>
    </Box>
  </Modal>
</div>
); }
```

Comment: You should create your Modal as a generic component, that means your Modal component will receive what you want to show as props (car name, car image, title, ...). Then your modal will show that info. So you will have just one Modal, and you call it when clicking the image, then you send the information of that specific car to your Modal component

Answer (score 0):

you can create a more generalized component for the modals that accepts props to customize the content for each car
create a new component called let's say `CarModal` that accepts `carImage`, `carTitle`, and `carDescription` as props.

Now you can use this component multiple times in the `Cars` component (the component in which you want to display your cars) to create separate modals for each car, you just need to pass the appropriate props for one

```js
// imports ...

const style = {
  // ...
};

function CarModal({ carImage, carTitle, carDescription }) {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const handleOpen = () => setOpen(true);
  const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={handleOpen}>Open modal</Button>
      <Modal
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
      >
        <Box sx={style}>
          <Typography id="modal-modal-title" variant="h6" component="h2">
            {carTitle}
          </Typography>
          <Typography id="modal-modal-description" sx={{ mt: 2 }}>
            {carDescription}
          </Typography>
          <img src={carImage} alt={carTitle} />
        </Box>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```js
export default function Cars() {

  // import carModal
  // ...

  return (
    <div>
      <CarModal
        carImage={Pagani}
        carTitle="Pagani Car"
        carDescription="This is a description for the Pagani car."
      />
      <CarModal
        carImage={Pagani1}
        carTitle="Another Pagani Car"
        carDescription="This is a description for another Pagani car."
      />
      // ...
    </div>
  );
}
```